# Generating css variables with scss @each not working

Tags: css, sass, ionic4

I am working with ionic 4 project and scss. I am having some strange behaviour, while I am trying to create a global CSS  variables using @each:

```
:host {
      $colors-availability: (
        early-day: #e8ab00,
        long-day: #854fa5,
        whole-day: #fe307b,
        all-day: #32773e,
        morning: #87cc93,
        afternoon: #4bb15d,
        late: #fa8072,
        twilight: #40e0d0,
        night: #16151b
      );

      @each $name, $color in $colors-availability {
        --ion-color-#{$name}: $color;
      }
}
```

This is my code in **theme/variables.scss** file. I am expecting to have all these variable with respecting colours, but the output is this:

[image]

I don't have the hash colour values. Any idea? I tried everything(color() function, etc..). Thanks.

Comment: you do with color like you did with name by adding `#{}`

Comment: You need to [interpolate](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) your variable: `#{$color}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this as below:

```
--ion-color-#{$name}: #{$color};
```

Comment: Answer score was 0, but it does work perfectly.. Thanks!